# Redirecting using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've got an odd redirect request, and I'm not sure if it is possible.

On the server we have a series of PHP files with a name similar to `/title-of-the-page-####.php`, where `####` is an unique integer ID of the page.

I want to be able to redirect users from `/####` to the full title of the page (as listed above).  Is this possible from within an `.htaccess` file, and if so, how?  (I would like to avoid listing all of the pages from within the `.htaccess` file)

Comment: Do you already have rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: @JonLin No, I'm starting with a clean htaccess file.

Comment: Apache can't really handle that on its own unless you do list every target in a rule or possibly [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html).  If you have an application framework with a router of some sort, it would need to be involved in resolving the long name for redirection.